# Render ViewComponent as string in razor pages getting NULL Reference Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I would like to render view component inside pagemodel in onget method. When i try to execute the  page I always get NULL REFERENCE ERROR. Can anybody help me with it. Here is the code i am using.

```
  private readonly IViewComponentHelper _helper;

    public MyPage( IViewComponentHelper helper)
    {
        _helper = helper;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> OnGet( string id,string type)
    {

        var result = await _helper.InvokeAsync(
                         "mycomponent",
                         new
                             {
                                 id= id,
                                 type = type
                             });
     }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can you provide the exception stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works.

1. Define a `ViewContext` property in your page

```
[ViewContext]
public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
```

2. Right before you call `_helper.InvokeAsync`, add this line of code

```
((IViewContextAware)_helper).Contextualize(ViewContext);
```

Hope this helps!